# After adding the matplotlib import statement stops the GUI tkinter window from appearing

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I'm trying to create a program to take user input and generates matplotlib graphs.  I have used Tkinter to create my python GUI to get user input.  After making the window I added a matplotlib.pyplot import statement and run the code the window no long pops up but I don't get any error.

I am having the same problem the seaborn module.  I have tried just "Import matplotlib" and this makes the window appear but I can't use pyplot.  I tried putting the pyplot call in a separate file and importing that file and the window still does not appear.

```
##barGraphGui.py


import Tkinter as tk

#from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Bar Graph")

c_width = 1000  # Define it's width
c_height = 450  # Define it's height
c = tk.Canvas(root, width=c_width, height=c_height, bg='white')
c.pack()

tk.mainloop()
```

With the import statement commented out a window appears but when I uncomment the import no window appears.

Comment: If you are using `tkinter` with `matplotlib`, you should use `Figure` instead of `pyplot`. `from matplotlib.figure import Figure` - does this work on your environment?

Answer (score 0):

Your code works when the import loads all from `tkinter` not `Tkinter`. I get the `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Tkinter'` error. Otherwise matplotlib works fine.

Comment: Thank you for answering! I am using Python2.7 so if I import tkinter is get the same ModuleNotFoundError name 'tkinter'

Comment: I updated to Python3.7 and everything worked, thank you so much!